# PHP If else Select MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable ($city) that pass through from other page and would like to select out from my database. However, I would only allow either one of the mysql_query to be selected when either of the condition is met but for my case it only work for the second condition. I apologize that I am lack of experience in php but would appreciate if anyone can assist here. thanks.

```
 $allcity = "AllCity";

 if (($city) == ($allcity))
 {
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE allcity = '$city'");
 }
 else 
 {
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE city = '$city'");
 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
 echo $id = $row['id']; 
 echo $lat = $row['lati'];
 echo $long = $row['longi'];
 echo $name = $row['name']; 
 echo $country = $row['country'];
 echo $city = $row['city']; 
 echo $price = $row['price'];
 }
```

Comment: Do `echo $city;` and see what you're getting from *other page*.

Comment: try `if($city == $allcity)`

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). Quit killing kittens.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: what are the row values for `allcity`? `AllCity` is case-sensitive here, so `allcity` won't work if that is the value for the row(s). Tell us, does anything echo at all? add echoes in each conditional and tell us what shows up.

Comment: use query `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE allcity = 'AllCity'");`  also check field value case-sensitivity.

Comment: also if you dont want to restrict quert then use `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload");`

Comment: ok, whatever. Wait for a magic answer, I'm out of this rabbit hole.

Comment: I have echo the variable ($city). Result is AllCity.

Comment: I just want to know is the way to do if else statement for mysql select. Thanks you paul for the help.  appreciate it i will check through again and change the mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, stop using mysql_.

However, if the `($city == $allcity)` doesn't match, you need to look at the $city-variable, to see if that contains spaces or other "hidden" characters breaking the match.

Do a `var_dump($city)`before the if/else, to check the string and see if it's actually 7 characters long. Also, to avoid capitalization errors, you might wanna do something like `(strtolower($city) == strtolower($allcity))` and see if that works.